# Memory managment in zf2

Tags: zend-framework2

How to make sure that when unloading a module form a page will free the memory used?
How ZF2 ensure that object created while loading a particular module is unset when i load another module? How can we check that?

```
For example i have two module

Application module and Album module

zftest -> load application module
zftest/album-> load album module
```

When switch from one link to another ? how can i make sure that no unused object are there in the memory space .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really wouldn't worry about this. ZF modules are very lightweight, and the classes they use are loaded on demand, so it's probably only the `Module.php` class that'll be loaded on every request.

Memory usage is rarely an issue for a typical PHP application. If you really think this might be a problem for your app, measure the current memory usage first to see whether this is the case.

Comment: with '1 lac' number of user in the system with 200 features means 1 LAC instance of application with 200 * 1 lac modules each , how can we make sure unused memories are freed and application performace is not disturbed. Whether in ZF2 is unsets the unused object?

Comment: You've just repeated the question and I don't really have much to add to my answer. PHP will handle freeing up memory, in a typical application this isn't something you need to worry about.

Comment: just to clarify i repeated the same. Need to build a sas model (multitenant approach )application using zf2 so little worried about the performance. Guidelines to follow